# PHP Array - Selecting 1 part of it

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

This will probably be looked at by someone and be able to say...this bit makes it work/change this and it will work however...

I have an array stored in the DB as

```
item1title:::item1product:::item1code###iten2title:::item2product:::item2code etc
```

However, i can not grab just 1 part of the array with...

```
  if(isset($itemConversations) && !empty($itemConversations)){
    $mAttributes = array();
    if(strpos($item['itemConversations'], "###") !== false){
        $mAttributes = explode("###", $item['itemConversations']);
    } else {
        $mAttributes[] = $item['itemConversations'];
    }
    foreach($mAttributes as &$mAttribute){
        if(strpos($mAttribute, ":::") !== false){
            $mAttribute = explode(":::", $mAttribute);
        } else {
            $mAttribute = array($mAttribute, '');
        }
$message .= '
    <td colspan="2">hello'.$mAttribute[0].$mAttribute[1].$mAttribute[2].'</td>
</tr>';
```

Can someone please show me what to change on the above so that i can select from the array in the way after $message please?

Comment: You don't need those `strpos()` checks. If there's no delimiter in the string, `explode()` will return an array with one element.

Comment: Your array is `$itemConversations` or `$item['itemConversations']` ? and why dont use serialize ? or json_encode ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you asking. The code above is works form me.

Comment: @lolka_bolka you get the array values returned with the $mAttribute[0].$mAttribute[1].  ???i just get single characters

Comment: You have a `</tr>` but no matching `<tr>`.

Comment: @MichaelGorman You would get single characters if `$mAttribute` where a string. But since it's an array returned from `explode()`, you should get the array values.

Comment: @Barmar See my answer, what is actually not an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fixed :

```
$message ='';
if(isset($itemConversations) && !empty($itemConversations)){
    $mAttributes = array();
    if(strpos($itemConversations, "###") !== false){
        $mAttributes = explode("###", $itemConversations);
    } else {
        $mAttributes[] = $itemConversations;
    }
    foreach($mAttributes as &$mAttribute){
        if(strpos($mAttribute, ":::") !== false){
            $mAttribute = explode(":::", $mAttribute);
        } else {
            $mAttribute = array($mAttribute, '');
        }
        $message .= '<tr>
                        <td colspan="2">hello'.$mAttribute[0].$mAttribute[1].$mAttribute[2].'</td>
                    </tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: i change : undefined variable $item : `strpos($item['itemConversations']` message not initialised `$message ='';` adding before td `<tr>`

Comment: How do either of those solve the problem he says he's having, which is that he's just getting a single character, not the whole element?